# Value not being displayed on Row_Selected

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created 2 user-defined fields on the Currency Rate screen(CM301000), "Rate Description" and "Currency End Date", as highlighted on screenshot 1. These two fields are populated from the Currency Rate Types screen (CM201000), where the Description field (Highlighted in screenshot 2) populates the Rate Description field based on the Rate Type ID of screenshot 2 and the Currency End Date (screenshot 1) calculates the amount of days that are left for each currency type to be expired based on the Days Effective field on screenshot 2.

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

The two fields on the Currency Rates(CM301000) screen's "Currency Rate Entry" tab works perfectly and updates accordingly. The Currency End Date is updated and correctly displays as the number of 'Days Effective' changes on the Currency Rate Types (CM201000) as well as the Rate Description if the 'Description' on the Currency Rate Types (CM201000) is changed. But I am also required to add the same fields on the Currency Rate screen's "Effective Currency Rates" tab and the fields on this tab only displays changes if the changes is being saved and does not show the changes as changes are made on Currency Rate Types screen as expected with _RowSelected without it being saved.

**Code Snippet**

```
   protected void CurrencyRate_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

        var row = (CurrencyRate)e.Row;
        

        if (row == null) return;

        CurrencyRateType currencyRateType = PXSelect<CurrencyRateType,
            Where<CurrencyRateType.curyRateTypeID, Equal<Required<CurrencyRate.curyRateType>>>,
            OrderBy<Desc<CurrencyRate.curyEffDate>>>.Select(Base, row.CuryRateType);

        CurrencyRateExt currencyRateExt = row.GetExtension<CurrencyRateExt>();
        if (currencyRateType == null) return;


        cache.SetValueExt<CurrencyRateExt.usrCurrencyEndDate>(row, row.CuryEffDate.Value.AddDays(currencyRateType.RateEffDays.Value));

        currencyRateExt.UsrDescription = currencyRateType.Descr;

        cache.SetValueExt<CurrencyRateExt.usrDescription>(row, currencyRateType.Descr);



        #endregion
    }
```

**Inspect Element of "Currency Rate Entry" tab**
[image]

**Inspect Element of "Effective Currency Rates" tab**

[image]

**NB: the inspect element of the field on "Effective Currency Rates" show CurrencyRate2, but it is still the CurrencyRate data class which is the same data class as the fields on the "Currency Rate Entry Tab"**

The two tabs uses the same database table/DAC but different views as show on the elements of the fields.

How can I change the code in order for the values of the "Rate Description" and Currency End Date on the Currency Rate (CM201000) screen's "Effective Currency Rates" to update even if the page has not been saved, but to display changes accordingly as changes take place on the Currency Rate Types screen?

Answer (score 0):

2 things,

**Doing Selects on RowSelected event handlers is really bad in terms of performance for the screen.**

**We should always avoid assign values on the row selected event handlers.**

You should instead try to change your code add search for the currencyRateType on the CurrencyRateFieldUpdated.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<CurrencyRate, CurrencyRate.curyRateType> e)
{

        if(row == null)
            return;
            
        CurrencyRateType currencyRateType = PXSelect<CurrencyRateType,
        Where<CurrencyRateType.curyRateTypeID, Equal<Required<CurrencyRate.curyRateType>>>,
        OrderBy<Desc<CurrencyRate.curyEffDate>>>.Select(Base, row.CuryRateType);
    
        CurrencyRateExt currencyRateExt = row.GetExtension<CurrencyRateExt>();
        if (currencyRateType == null) return;
    
    
        cache.SetValueExt<CurrencyRateExt.usrCurrencyEndDate>(row, row.CuryEffDate.Value.AddDays(currencyRateType.RateEffDays.Value));
    
        cache.SetValueExt<CurrencyRateExt.usrDescription>(row, currencyRateType.Descr);         
    }
```